# Transfering files to multiple iPads

Tags: ipad, usb, data-transfer

I regularly get around 30 iPads that require 10 - 20GB of images putting into the PhotoData folder.

As you can imagine this takes quite a while to do, I'm trying to investigate ways of speeding up this process.

I used to use an application called i-FunBox on Windows which would allow me to plugin around 10 iPads at a time and then I could scheduel the transfer of the images over night.

However I've recently started using Apple Configurater and would like to be able to do this process on the Mac.

There is a version of i-FunBox for the Mac but it only allows 1 iPad to be plugged in at any one time.

Can anyone else recommend an application or process I could follow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app called [fastboard](http://itunes.apple.com/NZ/app/id374795116?mt=8) that allows you to transfer multiple files to multiple iPads all at the same time.

Another solution might be to use Dropbox for iPad, create folders with the files you require and sync them with the right devices.

Yet another solution might be to FTP them across. There's a number of FTP clients available for the iPad.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

I'd like to use something that doesn't require an install on the device, like iFunBox.

Any other ideas?